# Getting "(553) File name not allowed" when renaming file on FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

In my application, I have files in FTP server one directory and I move that file source to target path. In this process, when I move selected source file that source file will not show in the source path, it will show only in target path.

I tried this below code, but I am getting error:

```
string sourceurl = "ftp://ftp.com/Mainfoder/Folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder/"
string Targetpat =
    "ftp://ftp.com/Mainfoder/DownloadedFiles/"+subfolder+"/"+todaydatefolder+"/"+susubfolder;
Uri serverFile = new Uri(sourceurl + filename);
request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverFile);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
request.RenameTo = Targetpat+"/"+newfilename;//folders without filename
response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();               
Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (553) File name now allowed.

```
response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //This line throwing the above exception
```

`request.RenameTo = newfilename`: when I set only `newfilename`, it renames that source same file name only.

How can I move this file to another directory within in same FTP server?

Please can anyone tell me. Thank you

Comment: Try adding the filename to `Targetpat`.

Comment: you will need target filename also. just folder name won't work with FTP

Comment: I added file name also like this `request.RenameTo = Targetpat + "/" + filename;` but still i am getting same error.How can i solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [I wrote you already before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41096905/850848#comment69400131_41096905):

> `request.RenameTo` takes a path only.

So this is wrong:

```
string Targetpat =
    "ftp://ftp.com/Mainfoder/DownloadedFiles/"+subfolder+"/"+todaydatefolder+"/"+susubfolder;
request.RenameTo = Targetpat+"/"+newfilename;
```

It should be:

```
string Targetpat =
    "/Mainfoder/DownloadedFiles/"+subfolder+"/"+todaydatefolder+"/"+susubfolder;
request.RenameTo = Targetpat+"/"+newfilename;
```

Comment: Thank you Martin PrikryI, your helped me a lot.When i Post about this always your replied me giving suggestions and all very help me. Thank you very much.